# How to select one attribute from 2 tables?

Tags: javascript, sql

friends I have two tables BrandCategories and BrandOffers. both tables having one column name "brandId". Right now i am selecting brandId using two independent queries that i have written below.

```
Select brandId from BrandCategories where categoryId   = "selectedCategory" AND isDeleted=0
Select brandId from BrandOffers     where discountType = "selectedDiscountType"
```

I want to select brandId in one single query which contains the result of both tables?? how can i do it ?

i have tried the following written query

```
SELECT brandId FROM BRANDCATEGORIES INNER JOIN BRANDOFFERS on BRANDCATEGORIES.brandId = BRANDOFFERS.brandId where BRANDCATEGORIES.categoryId='+brandCategorySelected+' AND BRANDOFFERS.discountTypeArabic="'+$('#DiscountDrop').val()+'" AND BRANDCATEGORIES.isDeleted=0
```

please tell if am wrong or right?

In my program i have written it like below:

```
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('(SELECT brandId FROM BRANDCATEGORIES INNER JOIN BRANDOFFERS on BRANDCATEGORIES.brandId = BRANDOFFERS.brandId where BRANDCATEGORIES.categoryId='+brandCategorySelected+' AND BRANDOFFERS.discountTypeArabic="'+$('#DiscountDrop').val()+'" AND BRANDCATEGORIES.isDeleted=0)', [], testing, errorCB);}, errorCB);
```

Comment: tell us if you are getting correct result.

Comment: 04-02 14:08:13.052: E/SQLiteLog(28112): (1) near "(": syntax error
am getting this error so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union` if you want to have the distinct values of both queries, `union all` if want to have all results from both queries (this might lead to duplicates):

```
Select brandId from BrandCategories where categoryId   = "selectedCategory"
union all
Select brandId from BrandOffers     where discountType = "selectedDiscountType"
```

Comment: I want to get only those brandId that have discountType = "selectedDiscountType" But they must be in the category.. Union is combining whole result –

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION for this.

```
Select brandId from BrandCategories where categoryId   = "selectedCategory"
UNION
Select brandId from BrandOffers     where discountType = "selectedDiscountType"
```

UNION is a shorter way to write UNION DISTINCT.
If you want to get also the keys that are in both tables use UNION ALL

```
Select brandId from BrandCategories where categoryId   = "selectedCategory"
UNION ALL
Select brandId from BrandOffers     where discountType = "selectedDiscountType"
```

Comment: I want to get only those brandId that have discountType = "selectedDiscountType" But they must be in the category.. Union is combining whole result